# Detect registered HttpListeners

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have several HttpListener services that are using different URIs (same port) on the same machine. Is there a way for one process to detect which other services are running and registered as HttpListeners on the same machine? They all share common code like this:

```
listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:" + HttpPort + "/" + AppName + "/");
listener.Start();
```

And I'd like for each application to be able to see and know that other applications are running and listening on the same machine and what URIs they're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this way (detecting if the port is busy):

```
System.Net.IPEndPoint[] tcpListenersArray =
    IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners();
bool portIsBusy = tcpListenersArray.Any(tcp => tcp.Port == port);
return portIsBusy;
```

You have active listeners information in tcpListenersArray array.
And you don't need administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

To show all registered HttpListeners on a machine you can run the command [netsh http show iplisten](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725882%28WS.10%29.aspx) using Process class from `System.Diagnostics` and parse the result:

```
var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c netsh http show iplisten",
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
};
process.Start();

while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // here you can parse to obtain the list of listeners
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Even when my process is running on localhost and I can connect to it with my browser, "netsh http show iplisten" doesn't return anything: "IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------"

Comment: If they are not showing in the list it must be probably because they were not registered using `netsh http add iplisten`.

Comment: You're right - my process runs as admin and doesn't need to register using netsh but they're still listening and working and can't be used by other processes so something in the http stack must be keeping track of them.

Comment: So you need a list of IP's like the one generated by running `netstat` in a command prompt but only containing processes that are HttpListeners? By HTTP listener you mean a server that serves http content?

Comment: I mean if I have 10 applications running using the code from my original question (but with different values for AppName), how can I get a list of all of them from one of the apps? It's not just IP's, it's the entire URI that each HttpListener is listening on.